# Получение значения поиска Яндекс на своём сайте

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте, скажите, можно ли как-нибудь получить значения поиска из яндекса на свой сайт?
Например, обращаться к яндексу и брать название сайта, ссылку и описание и выводить у себя?
Подскажите какие-то ссылки или описания. Спасибо.

Comment: В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

У Яндекса есть API для поиска - [Yandex.XML](https://tech.yandex.com/xml/)

В нем есть [определенные ограничения](https://tech.yandex.com/xml/doc/dg/concepts/restrictions-docpage/) на количество запросов. И стоит заранее почитать лицензионное соглашение.